# OnChange won't fire?

Tags: jquery

Anyone have any idea why the following code works flawlessly in Chrome, but in IE Edge it dosen't?

```
$("#SelectedCard").on('change', function() {window.location.href = '/?cardId=' + $(this).val(); });
```

Select code below.

```
  <select class="form-control" id="SelectedCard" name="SelectedCard"><option value="121212">121212 - Laddningsbart kort</option>
<option value="333333">333333 - Laddningsbart kort</option>
<option value="5555555">5555555 - Representationskort</option>
<option value="666666">666666 - Representationskort</option>
<option value="22222">22222 - Kort f&#246;r l&#246;neavdrag</option>
<option value="45443">45443 - Kort f&#246;r l&#246;neavdrag</option>
<option selected="selected" value="34343434">34343434 - Laddningsbart kort</option>
</select>
```

Going nuts. Thanks!

Comment: What type of element is #SelectedCard? A Select? Is there anything else significant about it?

Comment: Sorry, added SEELCT code. Nothing special about it though.

Comment: Does the console display any errors?

Comment: On Chrome, console shows no errors. On IE, I get:

SCRIPT1005: SCRIPT1005: Expected '('

But I can't see any missing ( anywhere. Checked the code a few times already.

Comment: Perhaps the missing '(' is located somewhere else in your code, and thus your code wont fire.

IE is more sensitive to syntax-errors in js and won't work as good as e.g. chrome.

Comment: You are probably right @JulianSim but I can't find it. Have checked manually several times. May be an include script I guess.

Answer (score 0):

the code you are using for onChange actually is working fine, however your window.location.href is something different from what you want to achieve I believe. You are setting the url, however not loading it. To check what you want to achieve I can suggest you [this summary article](https://appendto.com/2016/04/javascript-redirect-how-to-redirect-a-web-page-with-javascript/). See working snippet (exact copy-paste of your answer but changed window.loc to console.log):

```js
$("#SelectedCard").on('change', function() {console.log($(this).val()) });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <select class="form-control" id="SelectedCard" name="SelectedCard"><option value="121212">121212 - Laddningsbart kort</option>
<option value="333333">333333 - Laddningsbart kort</option>
<option value="5555555">5555555 - Representationskort</option>
<option value="666666">666666 - Representationskort</option>
<option value="22222">22222 - Kort f&#246;r l&#246;neavdrag</option>
<option value="45443">45443 - Kort f&#246;r l&#246;neavdrag</option>
<option selected="selected" value="34343434">34343434 - Laddningsbart kort</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hm not getting this to fire. Must be that ) i guess. Weird that Chrome is not reporting it though, and that it runs fine in Chrome. I'll check it one more time.

Comment: I checked this in IE (11.0.96) and Chrome (66.0.3359) and seems to work. window.location.href (and in general, url getting/setting) can work in mysterious ways in browsers. I found it best to set the window.location.href and then call a reload (if possible without loss of data). Or if you are using some MVC framework (like react or angular) you could exploit routing.

Comment: Thanks, will see if I can't come up with something.